# How can I display custom post types on a page?

Tags: custom-post-types

What is the code i have to put in the `page` to show the posts from custom post type?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could offer more details in your question.

Comment: There's an example here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#A_Page_of_Posts_for_a_Custom_Post_Type

Answer (score 3):

Easy: modify the query... (and add some comment on top to make a template out of this...)

```
$query_default = new WP_Query( array(
     'orderby'      => 'menu_order'
    ,'order'        => 'ASC'
    ,'post_type'    => 'custompost' // THIS IS WHAT YOU'RE SEARCHING FOR
    ,'post_status'  => 'publish'
) );
    if ( $query_default->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $query_default->have_posts() ) : $query_default->the_post();

        endwhile;

    else : // else; no posts
        _e( 'Nothing published so far.', TEXTDOMAIN_CONSTANT );
    endif; // endif; have_posts();

    wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Custom Fields page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) on WordPress codex, you can see the functions for Custom fields.

The "Template Tags" are the functions you generally use on your template:

- [get_post_custom()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) - Returns a multidimensional array with all custom fields of a particular post or page.
- [get_post_custom_values()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values) - This function is useful if you wish to access a custom field that is not unique, i.e. has more than 1 value associated with it
- [get_post_custom_keys()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_keys) - Returns an array containing the keys of all custom fields of a particular post or page.

Follow the links to each function to see examples on how to use them.

**UPDATE**: Ok, now I understand. You should try to add as many details as possible in your question for us to understand. As kaiser says, you should create a loopand add `'post_type' => 'custompost'` to get the posts from that custom type. You can use the [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function for this too.

Comment: i'm afraid you don't understand me... i have a custom post type called "custompost" and i want to display them on a wordpress page named "examplename"... how should i edit the page.php template to show the posts from "custompost" custom post type the same way as index.php shows normal posts?